# ordery_by filter is not working properly in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
data = models.Booking.objects.filter(center__isnull=False,org_type='homedx').order_by('-created_at')

return data.order_by( Case( 
                   When ( booking_status="resampling", then=Value(0) ),
                   When ( booking_status="sample not received", then=Value(1)  ),
                   default = Value(1)
                      )
                )
```

created_at is DateTimeField in Booking Model. Here i have ordered by choice field and for that i have used Case, When and Value method from django.db.models. But when i am using this it is ignoring order_by created_at. I mean when these two conditions are met. i want to get the data in order of latest date. Why it is not working? Thank you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you now have *two* `.order_by(…)` clauses, and as is specified in the [documentation of **`.order_by(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

> **Each `order_by()` call will clear any previous ordering**. For example, this query will be ordered by pub_date and not headline:
>
> ```
> Entry.objects.order_by('headline').order_by('pub_date')
> ```

You can add two fields to the `.order_by(…)` clause, so:

```
return models.Booking.objects.filter(center__isnull=False,org_type='homedx').order_by(
    '-created_at',        # 🖘 first field
    Case(                 # 🖘 second field
       When(booking_status='resampling', then=Value(0)),
       default=Value(1)
    ).asc()
)
```

This will thus first sort on the `created_at` field, and in case of a *tie* order by the `booking_status`. You can swap the two if you want the booking status to take precedence.